# Do Russians need to disclose their encryption keys to the Federal Security Service?

Tags: law, russia, cryptography

Is it true that in Russia, citizens have an obligation to send copy of all of their private encryption keys to the [Federal Security Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Security_Service) (FSB), even without receiving a specific demand?

**Update:** Someone replied on the chat:
http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21047851#21047851

Comment: See also: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24935/russia-need-to-disclose-encryption-keys-to-fsb

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) This site is dedicated to examining widely believed claims. I've searched around, and couldn't find anyone saying this (admittedly, I only looked at English sources). Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to where you heard this claim. (Russian sources are fine, but a rough English translation would be helpful for getting an answer.)

Comment: I was told to try asking my question on this forum. I read about this FSB thing years ago and now I need a citation for documentation purposes. Also, someone replied on the chat. Referenced.

Comment: The person who suggested Skeptics in a comment on the crypto site also explained you needed a notable claim. The chat reference (a) is not notable, but (b) more importantly, is NOT the same as your claim. I did find while searching that importers of cryptography using devices needed to register the *devices* with the FSB, but not the *keys*. Similarly, if you encrypt an email, no-one seems to be claiming you need to send the keys to the FSB. Where did you hear this claim?

Comment: I read about it somewhere many many years ago. If I could only remember where, I would tell you upfront.

Comment: I hope you understand that, if you are the only person we find who thinks this claim *might* be true, it isn't worth the effort researching it, especially as it might have been a misunderstanding or it might have been true briefly decades ago, but not now.